# How can I get the comitting user from a git hook?

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm writing a server-side git hook in gitlab, and I'd like to get the name of the comitting user. By this I mean: if Person A is the author of the commit message, and Person B is the person merging the commit into master, I'd like to get the username for Person B.

Is there a way to get this information in my hook from git or gitlab?

Comment: If you mean in a pre-receive, update, or post-receive hook, you can inspect each commit using the usual Git mechanisms, you just have to identify each commit you wish to inspect by its hash ID. (The post-receive hook has branch names available but you should not use them as they may have changed since your hook was invoked but before your code gets to the point of inspecting a commit.) Remember that these hooks may be delivered tags or other non-commit objects, and may be invoked by actions that merely *remove* commits.

Comment: Right, I can see how to identify the owner of a commit in the way you describe, but how do I identify the user _acting_ on the commit? In the example in the original post, if Person B is pushing Person A's commit, how do I retrieve Person B?

Comment: `git log --no-walk --format=%cn <hash>`, for instance, gets you the committer name, while `git log --no-walk --format=%an <hash>` gets you the author name.

Comment: Ah-ha, this works and I can see the proper diction now between committer and author. Thanks @torek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can refer to the `committer` line after executing `git cat-file commit <rev#>`

There is more information in the git website under the [Git - An Example Git-Enforced Policy page](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy) and find the command `git cat-file commit ca82a6`